# Which SDK do I need to ensure Windows 7 compatibility in Visual Studio C++ 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, compatibility, visual-studio-2017

I am building Desktop apps with Visual Studio C++ 2017 on Windows 10. Compatibility with Windows 7 and 8 is required.

May I use the latest Windows 10 SDK for this, or do I have to use the Windows 8.1 SDK?

Comment: Generate a temporary Win32 project using the project wizard and read the comments in the generated file `targetver.h` then look at the posible definitions of `_WIN32_WINNT` in `<SDKDDKVer.h>`.   Define `_WIN32_WINNT` with the appropriate value in your project build options.  Defining `_WIN32_WINNT` with the appropriate version removes newer/updated APIs from the windows header files.  The temporary project is just so you can see clean versions of the files, delete it when you are done investigating.

Comment: you may use latest sdk

Answer (score 14):

You can use the Windows 10 SDK to write Windows desktop applications compatible with Windows 7 and up. The minimum target version is controlled through preprocessor symbols (`WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT`). Set them to `0x0601` to target Windows 7 and up.

See [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) for details.